# How Can I remove duplicated Navbars?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have navbars and some tabs.

My React is constructed like below

```
...
return (
  <>
    <Navbar />
    <Router>
      <Route .... ..... component=Component1 />
      <Route .... ..... component=Component2 />
    </Router>
  </>
)

...
```

[image]

But for some reason, I want to insert different button groups for Component1 into right of navbars.

Now I solve this problem by adding navbar in every components and put buttons in each navbar (component1, component2, component3).

It works, but if my tab count is 10, I have to copy Navbar for 10 times.

I don't want this.

I 'll really appriciate for any help.

Comment: you can add right hand button group on basis of url or route selected.

Answer (score 1):

I'll break this down and try to make it simple,

This is your react router routes file:

```
<Router>
  <Routes>
    <Route component={<Layout />}>
      <Route path="/tab-1" element={<Tab1 />}/>
      <Route path="/tab-2" element={<Tab2 />}/>
      <Route path="/tab-3" element={<Tab3 />}/>
    </Route>
  </Routes>
</Router>
```

This is the code for the component called `<Layout />`, it includes the navbar:

```
import { matchPath, useLocation, Outlet } from 'react-router-dom'


export default function Layout(){
  const { pathname } = useLocation()
  const isActive = (to) => !!matchPath(pathname, to)
  return (
    <React.Fragment>
       {/* ---- Navbar ----- */}
       <div id="navbar">
         <div class="left">
          <Link to="/tab-1" style={{background: isActive('/tab-1') ? "green" : "grey" }}>Home</Link>
          <Link to="/tab-2" style={{background: isActive('/tab-2') ? "green" : "grey" }}>About</Link>
          <Link to="/tab-3" style={{background: isActive('/tab-3') ? "green" : "grey" }}>Contact</Link>
         </div>
         <div class="right">
           { isActive('/tab-1') ? <Tab1NavActions /> : null }
           { isActive('/tab-2') ? <Tab2NavActions /> : null }
           { isActive('/tab-3') ? <Tab3NavActions /> : null }
         </div>
       </div>
       {/* Page content */}
       <div id="container">
          <Outlet /> {/* this is by react-router, the actual page */}
       </div>
    </React.Fragment>
  )
}
```

Now, this will result in the following:
[image]

Based on the links that you'll click (Home, About, Contact), the actions on the right of the Navbar will change.

Now in case you wanted to pass data from the page itself into the actions at the top, you'll have to use react context, and **lift the state up**.

For example, you might be doing something like this:

[image]

Just in case, in my solution, I am using React Router v6.

Comment: How about actions for each button?
Each action button has its own handler related with each router component's state, props and so on.

Comment: @J.Porter, can you give the exact problem you have? what kind of action are you trying to invoke. typically that requires context setup. How would you like me to modify my answer? would you like to use Redux Toolkit or a simple react context?

Answer (score 0):

What you can do is instead of adding navbar in each component maintain one state in App or context that will keep track of which component is rendered and based on the component you can update the navbar.

The other approach could be if you are using different routes than based on route you can update the navbar. You can use `useLocation()` hook for the purpose or can use `window.location.pathname`

For example

```
<Route path="/component1" render={<Component1 />} />
<Route path="/component2" render={<Component2 />} />
```

```
function Navbar(){
  const location = useLocation();
  const pathname = location.pathname;
  
   if(pathname === "/component1"){ 
    return ( // return navbar for component 1 )
   }

   return ( // return default navbar )
}
```

Comment: But how about actions for button? for example, posting data from each component to server.

Comment: For that you can use context or redux to maintain and share state between navbar and component OR you can define and maintain the state in a common parent. @J.Porter

Answer (score -1):

You can use redux and store button groups for each component to solve this problem.

**Steps:**

- **Create redux for storing navbar-right-buttons.**

You can create redux for managing only navbar buttons.

Redux can't store components, so you have to create own component only for navbar buttons in each router component and store their router link in redux.

- **Everytime each component is rendered, update navbar-right-buttons with what you want.**

When you move to another router, you can dispatch actions to change navbar buttons url that are stored in redux to what you want.

> The most important thing is to add ***event handler*** in buttons for each
> router components
>
> In most case, event handlers are related to each router component's state.
>
> So, adding only `buttons container link` to redux is not perfect.
>
> You have to add not only `buttons container link` but also event handlers
> (e.g `edit`, `save`) in redux.

- **In Navbar you can get suitable buttons and use them.**

In Navbar, you can get navbar buttons url using `useSelector` and get button groups from it (also handlers for each button), if you are using functional components.

Comment: React components are not serializable in redux